# Play 2.3.4 Project won’t build anymore

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I am trying to build an old project of mine but it seems like most dependencies have been taken off of the internet:

```
./activator run

...

==== Maven Central: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.2.10/activator-launcher-1.2.10.pom

...
```

I tried digging for the older typesafe.com dependencies but couldn’t get my hands on any of them. Also tried sbt run but got a similar output.

Maybe I can find the jars somewhere so I could build this project again?

EDIT:

I managed to make SBT use HTTPS instead but the error now is that it cannot find the activator dependency:

```
module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.2.10

==== maven-central: tried
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.2.10/activator-launcher-1.2.10.pom
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue most likely is that Maven now enforces https, and the http URL's give a 5xx error. You need to convince SBT to use https for the dependencies.

Comment: Do you know how to convince SBT to use https @igmar-palsenberg? (Sorry for the delay, btw)

Comment: Create ~/.sbt/repositories , with the following content : 

maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Using SBT >= 0.13.6 should also fix this.